# Having trouble accessing a deployed application in WildFly 9.0.2 release

Tags: java, wildfly, ibm-midrange, wildfly-9

I'm having a lot of trouble deploying and accessing a war file in WildFly 9.0.2. We're running this on Centos 7 by the way.

So basically we have a war file called crownServices, and we've deployed this war file using the GUI. We also have a datasource called CrownDS that connects to an as400, so we added an as400 driver as well in the `standalone.xml`. We can start up the WildFly server and the logs show everything deploying with no issues. The trouble is actually seeing the application..we get nothing. Before I fiddled with some stuff I was just getting the generic 8080 splash screen, but now I'm just getting the word Forbidden.

Here's where the war file is deployed:

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="crownServices" runtime-name="crownServices.war">
        <content sha1="a3f0b1a0f1f66a109584c8de660b5a3a2abb02c2"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

And here's the datasource and driver configuration:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/CrownDS" pool-name="CrownDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:as400://172.16.10.83/</connection-url>
    <driver>as400</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>webstore</user-name>
        <password>pt7m1jqj</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="as400" module="com.ibm.as400">
        <driver-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</driver-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

And lastly this is the undertow configuration we wrote, and this is where I suspect the problem must be:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server" default-host="default-host" servlet-container="default">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost" default-web-module="crownServices.war">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

If there's anything I'm not providing let me know.

SO as you can probably guess, WildFly isn't something we're terribly familiar with, but we're struggling to get by with the documentation. Any ideas why this isn't working? I have a feeling there's a step that we're completely missing that should be obvious.

Comment: Please check Operating System's permissions (chown, chgrp, chmod). Ensure Wildfly folders are accessible to its OS user.

Comment: If you delete "default-web-module" attribute in host element of undertow subsystem, probably you will monitor generic 8080 welcome content screen. I agree with previous comment, you should check folder rights. Lastly, you could configure logging subsystem in order to deeper view undertow logs.